# extract data in exel sheet using macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, ms-office

you most probably going to think "what an idiot" but remember i never done any type of coding before so this is all new to me,
My problem are that i'm working on a HUGE excel sheet with loads of data that is not needed. i need to sort the data into a few columns, i only need column "A,K,AN,AQ" but in column "AS" i only need certain values (yes,no,blank) i only want the yes and blank values. like i said never done any coding before but i know that you can use an macro to do it so please help, how do i go about this?

Comment: @Jeeped thanks so much for all your help!! I sincerely hope you didn't hurt yourself in the process!

Comment: If you can provide a small example of your data (before and after the requested macro), you'll probably get much helpful answers

Answer (score 1):

before trying to get into macros, try to use functions with if else statements. They are quite easy to handle. Like: If (yes) then put it into X. Later, you could select all needed. Also, check the, how the dollar sign is used

[use this links](https://exceljet.net/formula/if-else/) to see, if it is something for you.

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way of getting this job done would be to:

1. Delete the columns you don't need.
2. Select all cells in the range you're interested in, click the Insert menu, and choose "Table".  If your columns have titles, select the box for "My Table has Headers."
   -This turns your data into an array so that Excel recognizes that each row is an entry (instead of thinking that the cells are unrelated).
3. Now you can use the filter icon in the column headers to select and display only the rows containing the values in column *X* that you're interested in.

Note that there are some limitations to what the table feature is good for, so, as always, whether this is a good solution for you depends on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: thanks this works fine for what i need for now, or until i learn a lot more about coding.